# cmake FindLAPACK.cmake and FindBLAS.cmake can not link lapack and blas

Tags: makefile, cmake, shared-libraries, lapack, blas

I have correctly installed lapack and blas on my laptop, and I can link by using

```
-L/usr/lib64 -lblas -llapack
```

in my Makefile.

I want to use cmake to create a Makefile and link lapack and blas, I am using FindLAPACK.cmake and FindBLAS.cmake provided by cmake in 
/usr/share/cmake/Modules/

The CMakeLists.txt is use:

```
find_package(BLAS)
find_package(LAPACK)
if(LAPACK_FOUND AND BLAS_FOUND)
   set(lapackblas_libraries "${BLAS_LIBRARIES} ${LAPACK_LIBRARIES}")
endif()

target_link_libraries(code_exe ${lapackblas_libraries})
```

Here `code_exe` is my executable to link lapack and blas libraries, I get an error

```
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `/usr/lib64/libblas.so /usr/lib64/liblapack.so', needed by `test/tensortest'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [test/CMakeFiles/tensortest.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Can anyone help me with that? Thanks a lot.

Comment: As you can see from error message, paths to *libblas* and *lapack* libraries are **joined**, which is not what you want. This is because you enclose them into double quotes when initialize `lapackblas_libraries` variable. Correct way: `set(lapackblas_libraries ${BLAS_LIBRARIES} ${LAPACK_LIBRARIES})`.

Comment: Thank you @Tsyvarev , that really help.

Answer (score 7):

remove the double quotation marks. such as:

```
set(lapackblas_libraries ${BLAS_LIBRARIES} ${LAPACK_LIBRARIES})
```